# How to write a Django ORM query for the reverse relationship in a one-to-one-field relationship?

Tags: python, django

I have two simple models and I just added:
related_name="service_client" to Service model...

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name
    last_name
    car # Client's car to be serviced


class Service(models.Model):
   service_name 
   service_type
   service_date
   client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Client served", related_name="service_client")
   
   def __str__():
       return f"Client {self.client} was serviced at {self.service.date}"
```

I want to show all clients data in form of a table...

| first_name | Last_name | Car (make/model) | Serviced? | Service date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Watson | Toyota Auris | Yes | 2023-02-01 |
| Bob | Kilicki | Toyota Corolla | Yes | 2023-02-01 |
| Mark | Smith | Honda Civic | No | -------- |
| David | Bobson | VW Polo | Yes | 2023-02-03 |
| Andrew | Hutchinson | Renault Clio | No | -------- |

(...)

But I need additionaly information if Client was served (car was serviced), if so - when (the date)?

How can I do that from views.py?

Should I make another field in Client model - for example boolean field holding information - client served: True or False?

Or better way is to construct - some more advanced - query which will retrieve data from both models, but how?

If it is common problem in Django, please point me to the right direction (in Django Docs). Don't know exactly what terms should I use...
Of course any example, is welcome, too.

**How query should look like this time (after adding related_name option)?** I want to somehow join data from both models.

Comment: you can keep service and service date in client model and map add a relation from client to service table, considering service name and type are static

Comment: To be honest I would like to have separate models, as they will grow soon (much more fields planned), this is just for example purpose. I don't exactly understand your advise - could you give some example code or point me to such?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add to fields to Service, a BooleanField for example that would say if the service has been rendered or not and another field to retrieve the date on which the service was rendered:

```
class Service(models.Model):
   done = models.BooleanField(defalut=False)
   done_date = models.DateField()
```

then in the template you can check if the service has been performed thanks to the Django template language and act accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but to show above table I need data from *two* models *at the same time*. How to retrieve these data from both models in views.py?

Comment: You just have to get all the users and services, pass them in context and get them in your template so you can build the table using the right values each time.